# In Java 8, is it possible to use JVM parameter to control when(or in what condition) to unload class?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, classloader, metaspace

In my JMeter test I find that JMeter keep loading classes javascript_gen_cmd__xxx and it makes the test can't reach the throughput I set.

[image: Class loading from JConsole]
When I click "Perform GC" button in JVisualVM, the classes are unloaded and the throughput is reached.

So i think it would help if I could indicate when the GC should happen,
for example when the total number of loaded class reach certain number.

I tried -XX:MetaspaceSize=120M but it didn't trigger class unload when the metaspace usage reached 120MB.

Comment: I think it is a different problem because that one is about custom class loader but this one is more about how to set the metaspace parameter so that the unloading process can be controlled.

Comment: The real issue here is the use of the Mozilla JS codegen that keeps creating classes over and over. It's most unlikely that _more_ GC will really solve a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=30 -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=10` should cause it to fill up quickly and thus trigger class-unloading GCs.

Alternatively `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses` and using CMS or G1 and firing `System.gc()` via a timer might work too.

Comment: I did the second solution;